# Navigate between Model/View/Controller keyboard shortcut?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm new to MVC.

I am curious if there are any built-in shortcuts to navigate between model/view/controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While inside a controller action:

- <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd> => Go to view
- <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> => Add view ...

The same actions are accessible in the context menu when you right click while inside a controller action.

The Model in ASP.NET MVC is quite an abstract notion and there's no keyboard shortcut allowing you to navigate to it as there's no clear definition of what this is. You could have a single controller action working with multiple Models or a single Model reused withing multiple controller actions, so it is not clear enough what do you mean by *navigate to model*.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out. Do you know if there are also shortcuts to navigate from the view to the controller?

Comment: @Shimmy, I am not aware of such shortcuts.

Comment: From view to controller is also ctrl+M, ctrl+G

Comment: It's also not working with VS2013 Ultimate with Update 2. Is there any other way or can we assing new key combination for add view?

Comment: Ctrl+M, Ctrl+G is working for me in VS2013 (with Update 3) to switch from view to controller as well as controller to view (based on the controller method your cursor is currently located in).

Comment: Make sure you're using the "General" keyboard layout for this combo to work.